# Line breaks in codemirror textarea MVC 5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, textarea, codemirror

I have an application that tests a user's ability to code. The textarea I am using to capture their code is by codemirror. I have a CodeTemplate for certain questions which is stored in my database. An example stored CodeTemplate is: `using System;\n\nnamespace Math\n{\n\tclass Math\n\t{\n\t\tstatic void Main(string[] args)\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}` which should theoretically print out:

```
using System;

namespace Math
{
    class Math
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is what it actually prints:

```
using System;\n\nnamespace Math\n{\n\tclass Math\n\t{\n\t\tstatic void Main(string[] args)\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}
```

============================

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Evaluation()
    {
        EvaluationPackage tester = new EvaluationPackage();
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Receiving Evaluation Package");
        var result = EvaluationPackageService.GetQuestions(11);

        // Put in question titles
        ViewData["question1"] = result[0].Text;
        ViewData["question2"] = result[1].Text;
        ViewData["question3"] = result[2].Text;

        // Put in code wrapper
        ViewData["codeWrap1"] = result[0].TemplateCode;
        ViewData["codeWrap2"] = result[1].TemplateCode;

        return View();
    }
```

============================

Here the problem section of my View:

```
<div class="question-header">
   <h2 class="problem-title">Question 1 - C# Coding</h2>
      <button type="button" class="problem-status btn btn-outline btn-warning-outline answer-indicator">No answer yet</button>
</div>

<p class="question">@ViewData["question1"]</p>
<div class="question-response">
   <form action="Test/Compile/" method="post">
      <textarea id="cs-code" class="code-area">
@Html.Raw(@ViewData["codeWrap1"]) <!-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM -->
      </textarea>

</div>
```

============================

I've already tried using `@Html.raw` and removing `@Html.raw`, and I have tried replacing the `\n` with `<br>`, but alas no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database INSERT was:

```
using System;\n\nnamespace Math\n{\n\tclass Math // ETC
```

The database SELECT was:

```
using System;\\n\\nnamespace Math\\n{\\n\\tclass Math // ETC
```

It was escaping the slash rather than the n. To fix this, the INSERT became:

```
'using System;' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + 'namespace Math' + CHAR(13) + '{' // ETC
```

`CHAR(13)` is for `\n`, and `CHAR(9)` is for `\t`.